# LINQ SelectMany is bind?

Tags: c#, linq

SelectMany will traverse an object tree:

```
class Agency { List<Employees> Staff }

IEnumerable<Agency> Agencies

IEnumerable<Employee> =  
from anAgency in Agencies  
from anEmployee in anAgency.Staff. 
select anEmployee;
```

Usually, i would always pick an Agency first, and use the internal instance of Staff to get the employees. But in the case of a government shutdown, I just want to list EVERYBODY to see who can cover.

In this rare case which is inappropriate for my object model, i can use SelectMany to arbitrarily traverse the tree.

What do you call this traversal? a cross join?  It isn't because the joining is already implicit in the composition of the Staff in the Agency object.

Is it bind? I don't know anything about bind.

Has it no other name than *Select, Many* ?!

Comment: SelectMany is map.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820866/what-function-acts-as-selectmany-in-jquery

Comment: SelectMany is isomorphic to bind. 
'
The first signature of SelectMany is isomorphic to the monadic "bind" operator, written >>= in Haskell. One reason it's included is to firm the foundation of LINQ on the well established framework of monads. That foundation makes LINQ polymorphically applicable to all kinds of things like composable state propagation, exceptions, continuations, alternatives, etc.: all the monads.'  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422958/how-c-sharp-compiler-choose-selectmany-when-translating-linq-expression

Comment: A correlated join. In SQL Server this would be a `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`SelectMany` in C# corresponds to bind in Haskell `(>>=)` or `flatMap` in Scala. The signature of `>>=` in Haskell is:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

so bind is an operation used to construct one monadic value from another.

In the case of C# `m` in the above signature is `IEnumerable`, `IObservable`, `IQueryable` etc. For `IEnumerable`, `SelectMany` is therefore

```
IEnumerable<A> -> (A -> IEnumerable<B>) -> IEnumerable<B>
```

or in C#

```
public static IEnumerable<B> SelectMany<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> first, Func<A, IEnumerable<B>> selector)
```

The meaning of bind depends on the monad type, for IEnumerable, each element in the input sequence is used to create a new sequence, and the resulting sequence of sequences is flattened to produce the output sequence.

There is another formulation of bind which may make this more clear. While monads are often described in terms of their implementation of bind, monads must also support two other operations, `map` and `join`.

`map` corresponds to Select in C# and looks like:

```
map :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> (ma -> m b)
```

so it is a 'structure preserving' way of lifting a regular function over a monadic value.

`join` has the type

```
join :: Monad m => m m a -> m a
```

so join is used to flatten nested monadic values. In C# this would look like

```
public static IEnumerable<A> Join<A>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<A>> nested)
```

`bind` can be implemented in terms of map and join as

```
m >>= f = join (map f m)
```

so to answer the original question, `SelectMany` corresponds to `bind` or `flatMap` in other languages. Bind is not just flattening, but can be seen as a transformation followed by a flattening of nested monadic values (e.g. sequences in the case of `IEnumerable<T>`). `join` for `IEnumerable<T>` does not exist in the current linq extensions.

Comment: Wow.  I don't understand what is going on here, but your examples merging IEnumerable with Haskell concepts are giving me the idea I CAN understand it.  Excellent treatment.  Thanks.

Comment: So `Join` is concatenation for `IEnumerable<A>`.  To take a different example, let's say we have something like `public static IMaybe<A> Join<A>(this IMaybe<IMaybe<A>> nested)` - `Join` would implemented such that either `Join(Nothing<IMaybe<A>>)` or `Join(Just<Nothing<A>>)` would equal `Nothing<A>`, and only `Join(Just<Just<A>>)` would equal `Just<A>`.  This makes sense from a black-box perspective, but internally, would/could there be any common implementation for `Join` between `IEnumerable<A>` and `IMaybe<A>`?  `IMaybe` this should be its own question...

Comment: @Bondolin - You could implement `join` for `Maybe`  using the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation but I think it would be more complicated than just implementing it directly.

Answer (score 4):

Out of .NET world it's often called "flattening", if that's what you're asking.  It flattens a two-dimensional result set into a single dimension.

Comment: only two dimensions? no SelectMany will traverse a three level deep tree.

Comment: Is it bind? is Bind flattening?

Comment: No, the "bind" that you refer to in your comments above is what enables Linq statements to be chained together. SelectMany returns an enumberable of results which gets bound to the next chained statement (the next statement acts upon the enumberable of results), the next statement returns another result that gets bound to the third statement etc.